# PostgreSQL: Trubles with copy data from one schema to another

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

Can you help me?

I'm trying to copy data from one schema to another with psycopg2 command:

```
columns = ('name', 'description', 'manufacturer')
source_schema = "public"
target_schema = "target"
table = "supplies"

query = sql.SQL('INSERT INTO {target_schema}.{table} select ({columns}) from {source_schema}.{table}').format(
    source_schema=sql.Identifier(source_schema),
    target_schema=sql.Identifier(target_schema),
    table=sql.Identifier(table),
    columns=sql.SQL(',').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),

)
```

But I get an error:

```
column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "target"."supplies" select ("name","description"...
```

Early I have created scheme 'target' as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS target.supplies (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR,
description VARCHAR,
manufacturer VARCHAR
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are turning a `SELECT` list into a record and also did not specify a column list for the target table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.supplies (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR,
description VARCHAR,
manufacturer VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.supplies (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR,
description VARCHAR,
manufacturer VARCHAR
);

insert into public.supplies (name, description, manufacturer) values ('test', 'test_desc', 'big company'), ('test2', 'test2_desc', 'small company');

--What you did:
select (name, description, manufacturer) from public.supplies;
                row                 
------------------------------------
 (test,test_desc,"big company")
 (test2,test2_desc,"small company")

insert into test.supplies select (name, description, manufacturer) from public.supplies;
ERROR:  column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
LINE 1: insert into test.supplies select (name, description, manufac...
                                         ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.


--What it should be:
select name, description, manufacturer from public.supplies;
 name  | description | manufacturer  
-------+-------------+---------------
 test  | test_desc   | big company
 test2 | test2_desc  | small company

insert into test.supplies(name, description, manufacturer) select name, description, manufacturer from public.supplies;
INSERT 0 2
```

So you need:

```
'INSERT INTO {target_schema}.{table}({columns}) select {columns} from {source_schema}.{table}'
```